# JAXB UnMarshall Collection element order

Tags: java, xml, collections, jaxb

lets say i have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<names>
    <name first="John" last="Doe"/>
    <name first="Jane" last="Doe"/>
    ...
</names>
```

This is my code:

```
final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Names.class);
final Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
final Names namesList = (Names) um.unmarshal(reader);
...
```

Now i could not find any documentation describing in which order these elements will be.
In my application it is important that the order which is in my XML file will be the same in the java object. I tried to look it up in the source but it was very difficult to understand. I hope somebody can help me on this one. Thanks.

kuku

Comment: As order in XML files **is** relevant, I'm **pretty** sure that the order will be exactly the same as in the XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For elements that correspond to a List property the order in the List will match the order from the XML document.

For more information on JAXB and collection properties see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: In your blog, you mention about marshalling... Is this also true for unmarshalling? Furthermore, do you know of a javadoc or documentation where this behavior is explicitly described? I've used JAXB for a while now, but I cannot be 100% sure that collection and xml document orders are matched, because I haven't found any mention of it in the documentation..

Comment: I am currently looking for a reference.  This is behaviour that we may have taken for granted in the JAXB 2 expert group (JSR-222).  This is the way that both the Metro (reference impl) and EclipseLink MOXy (I'm the tech lead) implementations work.  It's hard to imagine the behaviour being any other way from both a provider and user perspective.