# JAXB UnMarshall Collection element order - continued

Tags: java, xml, collections, jaxb

I am aware that almost the same question has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299943/jaxb-unmarshall-collection-element-order)). Despite that there is one interesting answer, there is still a loose end (in the case of unmarshalling) that also seems to apply in our case.

Here's our situation: we're parsing SOAP messages, the body of which is structured like this:

```
<complexType name="Body">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
      <sequence>
        <element ref="{http://[message=spec url]"/>
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Until now, we have assumed that the order of the  would be preserved in the (Array)Lists that result from the unmarshalling process. The **elements** are then written to a table and processed further in PL/SQL procedures. This is usually not sensitive to the order of the elements within a sequence.
It can happen thought that there are two **elements** in the SOAP message that refer to the same object. This is an error. It's caught in the PL/SQL code, which deals with it by logging the situation and rejecting the second element.

Our problem now is that, very rarely and (until now) completely non-reproducible, not the second **element** (as seen in the SOAP message) is rejected, but the first. Seen from the PL/SQL code, this can only happen if the data, that represent the **elements** in case, are being read in the wrong order (compared again to how they appear in the message).

Therefore, I was wondering if this situation might arise because the order of the marshalled **elements** is not explicitly defined.
In the answer to the above-mentioned question it looks like the order is defined in the case of marshalling with JAXB. The - as yet unanswered - question (by [chahuistle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589517/chahuistle)) whether this is also the case for unmarshalling, is not yet answered.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: How do you parse the message, DOM or SAX? Because with SAX, the order should be retained according to this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html (search for "sequence").

Comment: Ah - sorry, I forgot to mention that. We're using SAXB. I'll look into that article, thank you!

Comment: _"the parser starts at the beginning of the document and passes each piece of the document to the application in the sequence it finds it."_ -- this seems indeed to exclude the SAX parser as the possible culprit :) - thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

I haven't found the exact mention in the spec, but the intention is that order be maintained.  This is the reason that the main collection type used by JAXB is `java.util.List`.

> Until now, we have assumed that the
>   order of the would be preserved in the
>   (Array)Lists that result from the
>   unmarshalling process.

The MOXy implementation of JAXB will build a list based on the ordering of the elements returned by the underlying XML parser (DOM, SAX, StAX).  I can't imagine any JAXB implementation behaving differently, as it would be harder to implement and less intuitive to the users.

> Therefore, I was wondering if this
>   situation might arise because the
>   order of the marshalled elements is
>   not explicitly defined.

The MOXy implementation of JAXB will marshal objects based on the ordering on objects in the List.  Again I can't imagine any JAXB implementation behaving differently as it would be harder to implement and less intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this behavior in ***globalBindings*** declaration.

I'm assuming you are generating Java classes from the XSD files using XJC. Here is the most important part of the ***globalBindings*** element:

```
<globalBindings>
  [ collectionType = "collectionType" ]
  [ fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty  = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ generateIsSetMethod  = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ enableFailFastCheck = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ choiceContentProperty = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ underscoreBinding = "asWordSeparator" | "asCharInWord" ]
  [ typesafeEnumBase = "typesafeEnumBase" ]
  [ typesafeEnumMemberName = "generateName" | "generateError" ]
  [ enableJavaNamingConventions = "true" | "false" | "1" | "0" ]
  [ bindingStyle = "elementBinding" | "modelGroupBinding" ]
  [ <javaType> ... </javaType> ]*
</globalBindings> 

*collectionType can be either indexed or any fully qualified class name that implements java.util.List.
```

I'm guessing setting it to indexed should solve all problems.

Here is a link for [spec. document (take a look at section 7.5 and 6.12 (and subparagraphs)](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) or take a look at [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)

Comment: Until now we had this in our build.xml:

    `<target name="jaxb-generate-sources">
      <xjc destdir="${basedir}/gen">
        <schema dir="${basedir}/src/sources/xsd" includes="*.xsd"/>
      </xjc>
    </target>`

- no binding file specified. So this looks like a promising route. Thank you!